# How to ask about a position that requires security clearances?

Tags: interviewing, security-clearance

So I’m interviewing for a position that I was recommended for by someone who knows what I am good at and what I like, so I’m fairly confident that I am interested in the job, however...

The job description was about as vague as vague gets, not even any specific requirements in terms of technology use or expertise. This is because the job requires a fairly high security clearance.

So my question is, what kind of questions can I ask that will give me a better understanding of what the job entails, the subject matter, the lifetime of said position or subject matter, etc.

I have a few ideas, like asking the folks in my interview if the subject matter is interesting to them on a personal level or if they see themselves working in the same field for the next 10 years. Things like that, not sure if that will really answer my curiosities.

Comment: Do you already have this level of security clearance?  Or do you intend to apply for it once you have the job?

Comment: When I interviewed for the 3 letter agencies in the USA, they didn't tell me about any of the technologies they used. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @PeterM, Even if OP had the clearance already, the new employer still likely can't tell much as OP doesn't have "need to know".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They will probably be able to give you more details during the interview than they can post publicly in a job description, after you have signed some confidentiality agreement and past initial screenings.

You can also always ask questions on the form "how much can you tell me about...". The interviewer will understand that this is a special situation and it is in the interest of both of you that you can assess if the job is a good fit beforehand. Just be prepared that there are certain aspects they can not elaborate on until you have the security clearance.

Comment: Agreed, just ask like you would any normal interview. The interviewers will likely be able to give you a good idea of the job without revealing things they aren't supposed to.

Comment: At an interview, I was told that they were working on the Project for the Customer, and that the Project had hardware and software components.  The job was pretty standard for a software project, so I had a good idea what I'd be doing.  I was told I'd find what the Project was and who the Customer was if hired and after getting my clearance.